# gps stopped when i am calling from the application (automatically stop gps when make phone call hangup)

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, ios4

I have started gps and make phone call using openurl (tel) but when call is hangup it will automatically stopped gps.

actually i want gps on until i reopen app and stop gps by my deactivate button.

Comment: Do you have Location included in your background tasks?

Comment: yes i have define Apps require background task

Answer (score 0):

hi try this,

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.0f;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

i hope this will help you.